# Is it possible to call specific msconfig tab?

Tags: c#

I need to know that is it possible to call specific tab of System Configuration through c# application.

Till now I am only able to call `msconfig.exe` through my code i.e.

```
ProcessStartInfo pf = new ProcessStartInfo(
       Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "msconfig.exe"));
pf.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(pf);
```

Now I want to call only Single tab to open that is `StartUp` at button click.
Please get me some solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Msconfig takes a number as argument to decide which tab to show. `-4` is the StartUp Tab

```
ProcessStartInfo pf = new ProcessStartInfo(
       Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "msconfig.exe"));
pf.Verb = "runas";
pf.Arguments ="-4";
Process.Start(pf);
```

```
+--------------------+
|   Arg  |    Tab    |
+--------------------+
|   -1   | General   |
|   -2   | Boot      |
|   -3   | Services  |
|   -4   | Startup   |
|   -5   | Tools     |
+--------------------+
```

[blog with the arguments](http://unlockforus.blogspot.nl/2010/02/command-line-switches-for-msconfigexe.html) No formal docs from microsoft seem to exist with regard to this argument. This works for me on Windows7.